# Samsung Galaxy S3 4G notification center NFC button doesn't work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, crashes, system-error, nfc

**UPDATE:** This was fixed in the 4.3 update that came out for my phone lately. No need to think about it anymore, also I can't give any further details.

I have a quite new Samsung Galaxy S3 4G (GT-I9305). It is running an unmodified & unrooted version of Android 4.1.2. It works mostly perfectly fine, but there is a slight problem with NFC.

I have edited the buttons visible in the notification center. I have added the NFC switch to the buttons. My problem is, the button is not working. It is disabled, and has no green/gray indicator.

[image: disabled NFC button]

However, when I tap the S Beam button S Beam *and* NFC get enabled.

[image]

After this, if I tap NFC with S Beam either enabled or disabled, `System UI` crashes. When the UI reappears the buttons are as before tapping NFC, but now I can successfully turn off NFC, and also turn it on and off again. Restarting the phone brings the problem back again.

Another way to get NFC turned on while the button is disabled is to go to Settings > More Settings and turn NFC on. This also turns NFC on in the notification center, but again, trying to turn it off causes `System UI` to crash.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: @ScottOdle Not yet, as I'd like to keep my data.

Comment: It's probably your best bet to back up your data and do a factory reset.

Comment: @ScottOdle Thanks. I will however probably not reset it because the problem is not worth the effort. My question here was what might be causing this, if anyone happened to know.

Comment: What happens if you change the button order?

Comment: @LiamW Tried it, no effect.

Comment: @Pietu1998 does the device have NFC support? I have a strong feeling it's an issue with the actual device ROM.

Comment: Yes, it does. I have used an actual NFC sticker with my S3 while this issue has been ongoing.

Comment: S Beam is an app for NFC, could that be why?

Comment: @TheDoorkeeper S Beam uses NFC and Wi-Fi Direct, so it turns NFC on. This doesn't explain why the NFC button is broken. Also, I am looking forward for the upcoming 4.3 update, maybe it'll fix it.

Comment: @Pietu1998 If updating solved the problem, please write that as an answer and then *accept* it, so other visitors can see your question is answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the 4.3 update that came out for my phone lately. All done.